# How to remove blank page in jasper report when using page break

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I need add page break in sub report A, so that sub report B will start in a new page. And rows in sub report A is not determined. So, sometimes there is a blank page between sub report A and sub report B.

Question is - how to avoid the unwanted blank page? I know there is a 'print when' property for page break, but I can NOT figure out the proper condition.

Could you please give me some help?

Comment: How related these two subreports?

Comment: I have the same problem but in little different report structure. I have a report with subreports and I want to go to new page when all data in subreports are printed. So, I've added a page break after the subreports. It works correctly, but it adds a new blank page at the end of the document. Is it possible to avoid this behavior?

Answer (score 3):

You should place the page break exactly at the bottom of the band.
Example : If the "Detail 1" band is 100 height : Page Break (on Detail 1) top is 99 and Page Break Height is 1.

Comment: Thank you so much. Your solution worked perfectly and saved me a lot of time and frustration.

Comment: post with 12 years old, and still saved lives of many developers. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

May be, "When No Data - No pages" property may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. In subreport A, add another band with a height 1. This should be the last band. Put page break here.
It's work for me.